# I am getting such GET ERR_ABORTED 404 error after deploying react app to github

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I have made a react app and tried deploying it to git-hub pages. I guess I have messed up with some path specifications.

**Here is the file structure :**

```
 - public
      - css
      - image
      - js
 - index.html
 - manifest.json
```

**My html file looks like**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%./manifest.json">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%./css/default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%./css/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%./css/media-queries.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%./css/magnific-popup.css">


    <title>Piyush</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>



   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

   <script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
   <script src="js/waypoints.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
   <script src="js/magnific-popup.js"></script>
   <script src="js/init.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
GET https://piyushbhangale.github.io/static/css/main.8a155958.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure package.json with:

```
"homepage": "http://yourhomepage.com"
```